# How do i append a new object to an existing Object values without overriding ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I fetch the below response object values from an API call.

```
value = { 'tom.rivers@abc.com':
  { userType: 'creator',
   user: 'testUser',
   data: [ [Object] ],
     time: 1631610484971 },
 'tom.cruise@abc.com':
   { userType: 'responser',
     data: [ [Object] ],
      time: 1631610484971 } }
```

Lets say if I want to append a new object with key details as shown below, it gets appended without any problem.

```
value['tom.russel'] = {
      userType: "responser",
      data: [ [Object] ] ,
      time: 1631610484971}
```

**RESULT IS:** "

```
Value is" Object { tom.rivers@abc.com: Object { userType: "creator", user: "TestUser", data: Array [Array [Object {  }]], time: 1631610484971 }, tom.cruise@abc.com: Object { userType: "responser", data: Array [Array [Object {  }]], time: 19303478402 }, tom.russel: Object { userType: "responser", data: Array [Array [Object {  }]], time: 1631610484971 } }
> Array ["tom.rivers@abc.com", "tom.cruise@abc.com", "tom.russel"]
```

I want to append object with the same key again but different value like,

```
value['tom.russel'] = {
      userType: "user",
      data: [ [Object] ] ,
      time: 163161048907}
```

**RESULT IS**

```
"Value is" Object { tom.rivers@abc.com: Object { userType: "creator", user: "TestUser", data: Array [Array [Object {  }]], time: 1631610484971 }, tom.cruise@abc.com: Object { userType: "responser", data: Array [Array [Object {  }]], time: 1631610484971 }, tom.russel: Object { userType: "user", data: Array [Array [Object {  }]], time: 163161048907 } }
    > Array ["tom.rivers@abc.com", "tom.cruise@abc.com", "tom.russel"]
```

This overrides the existing value result, I want it to append it to the Object values, using which I display it in the frontend. I want to use this format because of the existing flow created. I tried transforming it to list and append the values, but i am not getting the right format.

**EDIT**: I want the value to be like this:Note based on the comments I tried transforming the Object to list and appending it.

```
{
   "Object"{
      "tom.rivers@abc.com":"Object"{
         "userType":"creator",
         "user":"TestUser",
         "data":"Array"[
            "Array"[
               "Object"{
                  
               }
            ]
         ],
         "time":1631610484971
      },
      "tom.cruise@abc.com":"Object"{
         "userType":"responser",
         "data":"Array"[
            "Array"[
               "Object"{
                  
               }
            ]
         ],
         "time":1631610484971
      },
      "tom.russel": "Object"{
       userType: "responser",
       data: "Array" [ "Array" [ "Object"{}] ] ,
       time: 1631610484971
      },
      "tom.russel":"Object"{
         "userType":"user",
         "data":"Array"[
            "Array"[
               "Object"{
                  
               }
            ]
         ],
         "time":163161048907
      }
```

Comment: What's the result you wish to see/get? Also, this has nothing to do with ReactJS. Maybe you're a bit misguided here?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to have different values for same keys. This is because Objects act as associative arrays in terms of how key and value are stored.

To conclude, one can't "append" because that's not a feature supported by `Object`s. And similarly you can't assign two values for same key because Objects only support one value per key.